# how to create an llvm Type

Tags: types, llvm, llvm-ir, bitcode

I'm trying to create a `TruncInst` with an `i8` destination type.
However, I **can't seem to find an appropriate type constructor**
when I look [here](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Type.html). I expected it should be something simple like:

```
if (val->getType()->isIntegerTy(32))
{
    TruncInst *ti = new TruncInst(val,new IntegerType(8));
}
```

But apparently it's not. I'm probably over looking something in the API.
Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Type::getInt8Ty(getContext());` will get a type for you, assuming that you have a way to get the relevant context.

You cannot create an IntegerType yourself because LLVM's design says that if two types t1 and t2 are the same (e.g. both are 8-bit integer types) and exist in the same context, then `t1==t2`. Much LLVM code expects to test for equality using `==`.

Comment: You probably created one in main(); you have to do that before you do almost any kind of work with LLVM. Or you can get one from e.g. [Module::getContext()](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a9c00c70121af456007404bd456047766), which returns the one that was created early.

Comment: The code is actually from a LoopPass run by opt. So I guess that the pass manager somehow must have created it right?

Comment: No, the pass manager [receives its module and context as an argument to run()](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1legacy_1_1PassManager.html#a148569282760e79e23c8fb292f33561f). The context is typically created first, then one or more modules, then other things such as a pass manager.